# Laravel-8 one-many/many-one relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to display category for each entry's page, but they all only display 'JavaScript.'

(A category can have many entries, but each entry has exactly one category.)

My Category model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function entries() {
        return $this->hasMany(Entry::class);
    }
}
```

My Entry model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Entry extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'entries';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'hours',
        'minutes',
        'category_id',
        'difficulty',
        'url'
    ];

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return date('F d, Y H:i', strtotime($value));
    }
}
```

My EntryController's show() method:

```
    /**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  Entry  $entry
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Entry $entry)
{
    $category = Entry::find($entry->category_id)->categories()->first();
    return view( 'entries.show', compact( 'entry', 'category' ) );
}
```

My categories table's up() method:

```
    /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 255);
    });
}
```

My entries table's up() method:

```
    /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('entries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title', 255);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('hours');
        $table->integer('minutes');
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('categories');
        $table->string('difficulty', 255);
        $table->string('url', 255);

    });

    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

Comment: What are you doing here: `$category = Entry::find($entry->category_id)->categories()->first();`. That's going to find the first `Entry` that has a `category_id` of let's say 1 (JavaScript), then you're accessing all the `Category` records for that `Entry` and taking the first `Category`, which could be the same every time... This doesn't make a whole lot of sense at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching entry by `category_id`, no need to find the `Entry` again.

```
$category = Entry::find($entry->category_id)->categories()->first();
```

Should be

```
$category = $entry->category;
```

`BelongsTo` is a singular relation and can be described as below.

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```